# Play WSClient url cannot access

Tags: playframework, webclient

I am using WS java client in my play framework. But I am getting the following response. 
My source is as

```
 WSRequest request = ws.url("http://localhost:9000/office");
 CompletionStage<String> response = request.get().thenApply(x -> x.getBody());

 String s = response.toCompletableFuture().get();
 System.out.println(s);
```

The output is as follow:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
>         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
>         <title>Error response</title>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <h1>Error response</h1>
>         <p>Error code: 400</p>
>         <p>Message: Bad Request.</p>
>         <p>Error code explanation: 400 - Bad request syntax or unsupported method.</p>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

I have disabled all the pre-enabled filter as "play.filters.enabled=[]". 
I really appriciate your suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to call a server running on localhost `http://localhost:9000/office`? using play ws client? if you did you check what are the param's for this endpoint http://localhost:9000/office

Comment: This is in the same application and without any parameter. It supposed to return a json document string.